# Could not load type '<typename>' from assembly '<assemblyname>'

Tags: .net-3.5, interface, reference, dependency-management, refix

I decided to modify some code today, and encountered an error that doesn't make any sense to me.  I have an interface called `IDatabase` and a class that inherits from it, called `Database`.  I originally just put `IDatabase` in the same assembly as `Database`, but I didn't like this because it would prevent another person from creating a new type of `IDatabase` without having the entire assembly.  I moved IDatabase into a new, separate assembly called `LibraryInterfaces`, and changed all of my references in the project.

The project compiles fine, but when I execute it, I get the error:

```
Could not load type 'Company.Database.IDatabase' from assembly 'Company.Database'.
```

This doesn't make any sense to me, because I moved `IDatabase`'s definition to `LibraryInterfaces`!  I double checked the files in the folder that is being run from, and the files are correct.  I even opened them up in Reflector, just to double-check all of the references, and those are correct as well.  I have also removed my `using` statement and have fully qualified all usage of `IDatabase`, and even that didn't do the trick!

Does anyone have tips for correcting this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into similar problems. delete everything in the bin folder, clean the solution and rebuild.

Comment: I thought those issues were way in the past -- I used to do that with VC++, but haven't ever run into it before with C#.  Thanks, I will try that now!

Comment: That absolutely did the trick, thanks!  I can't believe this is still something that has to be done.  Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: I have no idea what the actual reason is, but somewhere some references don't get updated.  glad the fix worked for ya :)

Answer (score 2):

You may have changed all your references, but do some of those references in turn reference the old assembly? This is one of the things the open source project [Refix](http://refix.codeplex.com) should be able to solve before too long (apologies for the shameless plug).